# Sort NSTableColumn by NSDate

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nssortdescriptor

I have table in table there is a column with dates in format of `dd/MM/yy` the entries are in `NSString`, now after clicking on the column header i.e. sort Descriptor icon column should get sort ascending or descending depending on sort Descriptor. In present its sorting in numeric order for example like

1. 10/23/13
2. 11/4/09
3. 5/2/06

But I want the columns should have sorted by date:

1. 5/2/06
2. 11/4/09
3. 10/23/13

I have written following code

```
- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView sortDescriptorsDidChange:(NSArray *)oldDescriptors
{
    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"date" ascending:YES];
    [fifiMainList sortUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {

    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat: @"yyyy MM dd"];

    NSString *date1String = [a valueForKey:@"date"];
    NSString *date2String = [b valueForKey:@"date"];

    NSDate *date1 = [dateFormat dateFromString:date1String];
    NSDate *date2 = [dateFormat dateFromString:date2String];
    return [date1 compare:date2];
    }];
}
```

But it's not working for me.

Do I need to write sorting code in `sortDescriptorsDidChange` or somewhere else? and I also need `sortDescriptorsDidChange` method in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :-

```
NSArray *yourArr=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"10/23/13",@"11/4/09",@"5/2/06",nil];
NSDateFormatter *format=[[[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]autorelease];
[format setDateFormat:@"dd/mm/yy"];
NSMutableArray *arr2=[NSMutableArray array];
for (NSString *str in yourArr)
{
    [arr2 addObject:[format dateFromString:str]];
}
    NSLog(@"Before=%@",arr2);
[self.arr sortUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    NSLog(@"After=%@",self.arr);
```